# YoutubeDL Can't get videos from YouTube playlist URL (Python. discord.py, youtube_dl)

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

I am currently making a Discord music bot on Python with discord.py and youtube_dl frameworks. The issue I am having now is to play the playlists, now it only plays single YouTube videos. Here is a part of my test code written to detect the problem:

```
def search_yt(item):
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        try:
            info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)
        except Exception:
            return False
    return info #{'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

song = search_yt("<some youtube url>")
print(song)
```

As I know, all the necessary information (id, title etc.) is in the **'entries'** part of youtube_dl response. If I try to request a single YouTube video, 'entries' is filled fine:
`{'_type': 'playlist', 'entries': [{'id': 'aGycmdH-4cQ', 'title': 'Shlohmo - Rock Music (Official Video)', 'formats': [{'asr': 48000, 'filesize': 1562444, 'format_id': '249', 'format_note': 'tiny', 'fps': None, 'height': None, 'quali ty': 0, 'tbr': 45.111, 'url': youtube link and so on`

However, if I request a playlist link or any video of this playlist link, 'entries' is empty so I cannot even get the info to play the videos from the playlist. **Here's how it looks**:

`{'_type': 'playlist', 'entries': [], 'id': 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf9RRm7Yy3ETOyJN1TsN7nh3l4aujtx3f', 'extractor': 'youtube:search', 'webpage_url': 'ytsearch:https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf9RRm7Yy3ETOyJN1T sN7nh3l4aujtx3f', 'webpage_url_basename': 'playlist', 'extractor_key': 'YoutubeSearch'}`

The only thing that seems suspicious here to me is the 'id' contains the full link, while in 'ytsearch' it is splitted on two lines for some reason.

If you have any ideas of how to deal with this issue, I'd be very thankful for every bit of help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `youtube-dl`, you can use a better, more maintained version `yt-dlp`

Here is the code:

```
import json
import yt_dlp
URL = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5CCDFBBE2143D7CB"
ydl_opts = {}
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(URL, download=False)

    # ℹ️ ydl.sanitize_info makes the info json-serializable
    print(json.dumps(ydl.sanitize_info(info)))
```